# ORDER BY on different columns in different directions in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, syntax

I have a table defined by:

```
    CREATE TABLE bar_table (
        _id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        index INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '65535',
        _date DATE
    )
```

My basic select statement is:

```
SELECT * FROM bar_table ORDER BY <your-clause-here>
```

How do I order my selection by index ascending, and date descending? i.e. small indexes come before large indexes. In the event that two indexes are the same, the later date is to come first.

The documentation is pointing me towards COLLATion, ubut I'm not really sure what that is.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While I know that you already have your own answer up here, I think it's pertinent to go into the details at work here.

First, the `order by` clause goes in order of columns or expressions specified. In this case:

```
order by index asc, _date desc
```

That sorts by `index` smallest to largest (`asc`ending), and *then* `_date` largest to smallest (`desc`ending). While `asc` is the default value, I generally include it when I have multiple columns going opposite directions, like you do here.

You can also include expressions in your `order by`:

```
order by case when index < 0 then 1 else 0 end desc, _date desc
```

This would put all of the negative `index` rows at the top, and then sort those by `_date`. Using expressions in your `order by` clause is very effective in certain circumstances.

Now, you mentioned [collation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation), and a little confusion as to what that is. Collation is how the database treats capital and accents in string comparisons. With a Captial-Sensitive collation, `'abc' != 'ABC'`. However, with a Captial-Insensitive collation, `'abc' = 'ABC'`.

It should be noted that collation is *not* a character set. That's usually determined by data type (`varchar` == ASCII, `nvarchar` == Unicode). Collation determines how strings are compared, not what character sets are available for use.

Moreover, collation is also important with certain languages. Given a Latin collation, you just have to worry about capitalization and accents, but given a Danish collation,  `'aa' = 'å'`.<sup>1</sup> So you can see that collation plays a big part in determining sorting and comparisons for different languages, as well.

Collation is very important when ordering, because it determines how strings will be ordered given different capitalizations and accents. That's why it keeps coming up in your searches. Collation is important, and it even [affected StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15417) this week!

<sup>1</sup><sub>: Thanks to Michael Madsen for pointing out this specific example.</sub>

Comment: Collation is not just a matter of comparing capital letters and accents, it is sorting of characters in general, including treating sequences of regular characters as equivalent to some other character. For example, in Danish, "aa" is still a valid way of writing "å", even though å is the last letter in the Danish alphabet, so using a Danish collation would sort text accordingly (it's usually correct given the expected language, and the computer can't decide on it's own if it's a case like the German city Aachen, where aa is obviously not used as å).

Comment: Thanks. I'm fairly sure I tried your suggestion of `order by index asc, _date desc`, but with no success.

Comment: @jamesh: Really? Are you sure? Because that would work on nearly every single RDBMS out there. The only time I could think of where this wouldn't work is if `_date` was a `varchar` field rather than a `datetime` one. Perhaps you need to encapsulate `index` with backticks, like `\`index\``.

Comment: @Eric: I just tried it again. My bad. Not sure what I was doing wrong. Thanks.