# How to sort SQLite table result in specific order?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table in my sqlite database, i need to sort it in this way..

```
467958  1010  49611
467958  1010  49612
467958  1010  49613
467958  1010  49614
467958  1010  49615
467958  1010  49616
467958  1010  49617
467958  1010  49618
467958  1010  49619
467958  1010  496110
467958  1010  4961other
```

but i am getting this.

```
467958  1010  4961other
467958  1010  49611
467958  1010  49612
467958  1010  49613
467958  1010  49614
467958  1010  49615
467958  1010  49616
467958  1010  49617
467958  1010  49618
467958  1010  49619
467958  1010  496110
```

my code is.

```
cursor = db.query(TABLE_SGQ_LIVE, new String[] {SGQ},
                    null, null, null, null, Q_Id + " ASC, " + G_id  + " ASC");
```

I mean sorting (integer first and string second).

Comment: Your `query()` call selects only a single column (`SGQ`), which does not correspond with the data shown. Please label the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to split and then sort.

First of all, your table design seems to be wrong. If you want to sort based on multiple conditions, they should be stored as separate column. So redesign your table.

If you cannot do that for some reason, then you cannot sort it in SQL query. 
Get the results in an Array, and sort them in Array by writing your custom sort order logic.

Comment: // and Q_Id ,G_id are fields in table. read the comment on code.

Comment: this line,.... `// where '467958X1010X496110' 'X' is the separator of SID,G_id,Q_ID.` just to showing the values of columns to understand what type of data is in the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that you probably have different columns in DB, but you wrote the example with 'X' as separator !! Why ? That confused me !!

So basically you want to sort based on different colums with different sort orders..

DONT use the db.query method.  Prepare a SQL and execute the query using rawQuery method.

SQL should be :

```
select * from my_table order by col_a ASC, col_b DSC
```

Comment: See the answer described here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319793/order-by-on-different-columns-in-different-directions-in-sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer:

```
select * from TABLE_SGQ_LIVE order by Q_Id asc, G_id*1, G_id desc
```

See: [Sort numbers (and numbers+letters) with sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189511/sort-numbers-and-numbersletters-with-sqlite)